# Meshlab - showing non manifold edges

Tags: meshlab

I have an STL file which is giving me problems, and I suspect is non manifold.  Reading up on how to clean it, it seems that MeshLab is the tool for the job.  I've installed version 2022.02 (on Linux).

However the instructions on how to identify the non-manifold edges seem to suggest there should be an option on the Render menu for 'show non manif edges', but this isn't present on my system - has it been removed, or is there another way to find this feature?

[image: MeshLab screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option you search is not there, but at the last tab in the visualization options panel.

An image is worth a thousand words...

[image]

Also, you probably are interested in press `Ctrl-F` to launch the filter search box and type `manifold` to find the operations that meshlab offers to eliminate manifold vertex or edges. Also you are probably interested in the `Merge Close Vertices` filter, which solves a common problem in stl files.

[image]